# Is there a way to separate different args in the same step in the yaml build config file for google cloud build?

Tags: docker, yaml, google-cloud-build

I wanted to test out google cloud build to run unit tests for my application but I'm having trouble installing dependencies.

For a buildconfig that looks like this,

```
  - name: ubuntu
    args:
      - apt-get
      - update;
      - apt-get
      - install
      - '-y'
      - curl
```

I get the following output.

`E: The update command takes no arguments`

Is there a way to separate the update command and the install command? I know they have to be in the same step but neither ";" or "&&" is working as they're both read in as arguments for the update command.

Comment: Why can't you write these installation steps in your image `Dockerfile` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try following approaches

```
       steps:
        - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
          entrypoint: 'bash'
          args: ['-c', "apt-get update 
                  && apt-get install curl -y " 
          ]
```

Another way may be

```
steps:
    - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
      entrypoint: 'bash'
      args: 
        - '-c'
        - |
           apt-get update
           apt-get install curl -y
```